# Associative Array - duplicated key values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am doing a simple shopping application were user may choose books from the store based on the title, price, quantity etc. At the moment all details of the books are kept in an associative array which looks like this:

```
$menu = array(
array ('id' => '1', 'catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'Alex','price' => 4.95, 'desc' => 'bbbb'),

array('id' => '2','catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'David ','price' => 5.95, 'desc' => 'sss'),);
```

}

What I am trying to achieve is  merge or remove duplicated entries of book id's also each book title will be printed in one single row containing 'title', 'id', 'price'

for example:

1. `Alex qty:2 price 4.95`
2. `David qty:2 price 5.95`
   and so on...

And this is my cart file:

```
        $buy = array();
        $qty = 0;
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION['buy'] as $id) {


            foreach ($menu as $book ) {

                if ($book['id'] == $id) {
                    $buy[] = $book;
                    $total += $book['price'];

                }
            }
        }
    }


    if (count($buy) > 0)
        if (count($book) > 0)
    {
        echo"<table>";
        echo"<tr><th>Item Description</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

        foreach ($buy as $book){


            $f_price = sprintf("%0.2f", $book["price"]);

            echo"<tr><td>" .$book["title"] ."</td>";
            echo"<td>" .$qty."</td><";
            echo"<td>" .$f_price."</td></tr>";
        }

        echo"<tr><td>Total</td><td>".$total."</td></tr>";
        echo"</table>";
    }
```

I will be extremely grateful for any help or advice cause I spent long long time to resolve this problem trying use unique functions, for statements foreach loop but in vain I am still novice also please try to be a little tolerant . Cheers!

Comment: what about array_unique() ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @Calimero And what help is from array_unique?

Comment: Look into array_count_values() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but this should do what you want using [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to obtain the quantities you were looking for along with a few changes to make the script more efficient and easier to manage.

```
<?php
//the ids of the items the user wants to buy
$ids=$_SESSION['buy'];

//Your database of items
$menu = array(
    array ('id' => '1', 'catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'Alex','price' => 4.95, 'desc' => 'bbbb'),
    array('id' => '2','catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'David ','price' => 5.95, 'desc' => 'sss')
);
//Create a reverse look-up for the database
$lookUp=array();
foreach($menu as $i=>$v)$lookUp[$v['id']]=$menu[$i];



//populate the cart with items, their quantities, and a total
$cart = array();
$total = 0;
foreach (array_count_values($ids) as $id=>$quantity)
{

    if (!array_key_exists($id, $lookUp))continue;
    $item=$lookUp[$id];
    $itemTotal=$item['price']*$quantity;
    $total+=$itemTotal;
    $cart[]=array_merge($item,array('quantity'=>$quantity,'itemTotal'=>$itemTotal));
}


if(count($cart) > 0)
{
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Item Description</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Item Total</th></tr>';
    foreach ($cart as $item)
    {

    echo sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%0.2f</td><td>%0.2f</td></tr>',
        $item["title"],$item['quantity'],$item['price'],$item['itemTotal']);
    }
    echo '<tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Total</td><td>'.$total.'</td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: This is just outstanding! Can you explain me what does the 'lookUp' actually do and what is the purpose of '$v' variable in this case?

Comment: $lookUp creates a reverse look-up for your database of items.
Let's say the user's session contains the items: `array(1,2,2,2,1)`
For the item with the id '1' we want this:
`array ('id' => '1', 'catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'Alex','price' => 4.95, 'desc' => 'bbbb')`
How do we fetch it? 
It is located in `$menu[0]` but who says you won't have missing ids if you delete an item at some point? Thus we want to be able to get the index of the item in $menu. So we consult $lookUp['1'] which returns 0. Then we use the 0 to get the the item information.




$lookUp

Comment: `foreach($menu as $i=>$v)`
This loops through the $menu twice.
The first time $i will be 0 and $v will be `array ('id' => '1', 'catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'Alex','price' => 4.95, 'desc' => 'bbbb')`.
The second time $i will be 1 and $v will be `array('id' => '2','catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'David ','price' => 5.95, 'desc' => 'sss')`.
Regarding the assignment:
`$lookUp[$v['id']]=$menu[$i];`
The first time it assigns `$lookUp[1]=0;`
The second time it assigns `$lookUp[2]=1;`

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can move on with my application.

Comment: Please make sure to thumb-up helpful answers and pick a best answer.

Comment: Hi Ultimater, I have done a little progress however there is a little bug because it is not increments number of items properly. When I add first and always first item to the basket the basket counter still shows no item but any other items is properly countable. I have to ask one more thing cause I cant figure yet how to implement delete Item function in to this code. Would you be able to give some hints how to do it? I am sorry for this but I need to accomplish my project for two weeks an I am getting little bit anxious. By the way that was very nice piano playing :)

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't like extended conversation. Either enter a chat over here for extended conversation or contact me via email as explained in my profile.

Comment: I tried to find out what will be the best option to contact with you but i need 20 reputation to chat with other users so it is not very useful. Do I need to register my details first on webdeveloper.com to get you email address?

Comment: I can't write anything

Comment: As explained in [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/466314/ultimater) my site ultimater.net has a [catch-all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-all) email for my site ultimater.net. Meaning you can send an email to anything at ultimater.net and it forwards to my primary email.

Comment: Hi, I tried to get to contact with you but catch all method is only available after configuration whole bunch of staff. Is it any other option to get contact with you, mate?

Comment: I wrote my primary email address for you in [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44281/ultimaters-room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44281/ultimaters-room)

Comment: The bad thing is that beginner users cant even chat also I need to contribute a little to get higher rank.  I will send you an email today  but a bit later cause I am little bushed doing  my application, but in California must be around 8pm If I am right. Great!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just based off the id, when you build the array, store the book id as the key in the larger array, so your end array would be:

```
$books = array(
   1=> array ('id' => '1', [...]),
   2=> array ('id' => '2', [...])
);
```

You could also add some code that checks when you try to assign a value to that array to see if the key is already set.

```
if(!isset($books[$book_id])){
  //Add to the array
}else{
   //Maybe display an error?
}
```

PS: Category only has one `a` in it.

Comment: Guessing that down vote is spiteful?  This is the right way to organise the collection - otherwise any attempt to enforce uniqueness is exhaustive.

Comment: @Hardy I don't think you understand my answer. First of all, I didn't say anything about the session. Secondly, the OP question is about preventing duplicates. Your response here indicates you WOULD have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty cumbersome way to make a stock overview of the books in your collection, but that aside :)

If i was to work with an array like that, (and i would never do that :)) i would first select all unique keys, and then go through them one by one, counting the number of times it occur in the `$menu` array.
As follows:

```
$unique_books = array_unique($menu);

foreach($unique_books as $book){

 $qty = array_keys($menu, $book["id"])
 $book["qty"] = $qty;
 $stock = $book;

}
```

As you can see, now $stock will be the unique array, with a qty added to it, containing the number of times, the id was seen in $menu.
This is just a fast code block, and should be testet, but the theory works i think. As i mentioned before, the way you'r making this in the first place, is not very smart, and you should really reconsider the whole thing imo :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna duplicates simple use the book_id as the key of buy array

Example:

```
 $menu = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'Alex','price' => 4.95, 'desc' => 'bbbb'),
    array('id' => '2','catagory' => 'newbooks','title' => 'David ','price' => 5.95, 'desc' => 'sss')
);
$session=array(1,2,2,2,1);
$buy = array();

        foreach ($session as $id) {
            foreach ($menu as $book) {
                if ($book['id'] == $id) {
                    if(isset($buy[$id])){
                        $buy[$id]['qty']++; // increase quantity
                        $buy[$id]['total'] += $book['price']; // total price only for this id
                        $buy['total'] += $book['price']; // All ids price total
                    }else{
                        $buy[$id] = $book; // assign new id to the buy array
                        $buy[$id]['qty'] = 1; // quantity reset to 1
                        $buy[$id]['total'] = $book['price']; // id price
                        $buy['total'] += $book['price']; // total price
                    }
      }  
   }
}
print_r($buy);
```

You can test it here!

http://codepad.org/wH2WskLG

Comment: Perfecto, this is exactly what I have been trying to achieve. Can you be more more specific how to increment quantity and price for each book id?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of merging duplicates you should add book id and qty as array row to session.

On session start..

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['buy']))
  $_SESSION['buy'] = array();
```

When adding new..

```
$new_book = $added_book; // just for example
$qty = $added_qty; // Added qty

// Check if book already exists in shopping cart and update qty
if (array_key_exists($new_book['id'], $_SESSION['buy'])) {
   $_SESSION['buy'][$new_book['id']] += $qty;
} else {
   $_SESSION['buy'][$new_book['id']] = $qty;
}
```

Then on shopping cart view just loop thru your items..

```
 foreach($menu as $book ) {


   if (array_key_exists($book['id'], $_SESSION['buy'])) {
      // User bought this book..

      $qty = $_SESSION['buy'][$book['id']];
   }

 }
```

Comment: @jessica Are you expecting that i write whole code for handling shopping cart? This is just example of how it should be done. Check my updated answer..

Comment: You original answer did not contain anything that would have to do with preventing duplicates. Plus, your new code is riddled with issues. Don't take it so personally when people critique you, please be mature about it.